# Class should be shown/hidden, depending on its content - but it only gets hidden

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I'm working on a PHP-chat right now.
When a user logs in he automatically sends a message "logged in" that is shown to everybody, when he logs out he automatically sends "logged out" that is shown to everybody (except him of course).
When all users logged out, all messages are deleted automatically.

I'm now working on a function that tells you, whether you are alone in the chatroom or not.
I want to solve this using JavaScript. The script I use right now counts how often the term "logged in" and the term "logged out" appears in the chat history (yeah, not the ultimate solution, but absolutely sufficient for my use)

Here's the code:

```
function countverlassen(){
    var temp = document.body.innerText;

// the g in the regular expression says to search the whole string 
// rather than just find the first occurrence
var countverlassen = (temp.match(/verlassen/g) || []).length +1;

console.log(countverlassen);
}

function countbetreten(){
    var temp = document.body.innerText;

// the g in the regular expression says to search the whole string 
// rather than just find the first occurrence
var countbetreten = (temp.match(/betreten/g) || []).length;

console.log(countbetreten);
       if (countbetreten >= 2 && countbetreten != countverlassen){
           $('.alleine').hide();
       }
else if (countverlassen >= 2 && countbetreten == countverlassen) {
           $('.alleine').show();
       }
}
```

The class "alleine" only contains the text "You are alone in here right now".
When another user logs in this should be hidden, when all other users except you log out it should be displayed again.
Hiding the class works fine, but it just won't reapper again when everybody else logged out.

You can see it in action here: http://team3.digital-cultures.net/index.php#
Just pick a name and chosse a start / destination from the dropdown.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT: For testing purposes you can just enter "betreten" ("logged in" in German) and "verlassen" ("logged out in German") in the chat, no need to log in with multiple accounts :)

Comment: you need to keep polling using ajax to check the count of users logged and show based on it

Comment: This might incur polling or websocket to go.

Comment: I'm doing that basically - every time a new message is send the functions get loaded and count again (you can see it in the console log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `return` to get a value out. Using the function name is only creating a new local variable. I've renamed the var to make this clearer.

```
function countverlassen(){
    var temp = document.body.innerText;

    // the g in the regular expression says to search the whole string 
    // rather than just find the first occurrence
    var verlassenCount = (temp.match(/verlassen/g) || []).length +1;

    console.log(verlassenCount);
    return verlassenCount;
}
```

Use `countverlassen()` to call the function and get the value. Store the value instead of calling the function every time.

```
function countbetreten() {
    var temp = document.body.innerText;

    // the g in the regular expression says to search the whole string 
    // rather than just find the first occurrence
    var betretenCounter = (temp.match(/betreten/g) || []).length;
    var verlassenCounter = countverlassen();

    console.log(betretenCounter);
    if (betretenCounter >= 2 && betretenCounter != verlassenCounter) {
        $('.alleine').hide();
    } else if (verlassenCounter >= 2 && betretenCounter == verlassenCounter) {
        $('.alleine').show();
    }
}
```